# Update dynamiclly parameters on jenkins plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins, jelly

I am writing Jenkins plugin.
I have a select element that should get its value from the server.
by the documentation, should do the following: 
In Descriptor file:

```
public ListBoxModel doFillGoalTypeItems() {
    ListBoxModel items = new ListBoxModel();
    for (BuildGoal goal : getBuildGoals()) {
        items.add(goal.getDisplayName(), goal.getId());
    }
    return items;
}
```

Then, use a  tag to enclose the normal select tag.

In Jelly file

```
<f:entry field="goalType" title="Choose Goal Type">
   <f:select />
</f:entry>
```

My issue is the method called only in the initialization, and I want that the parameter will updated from the server each event that happened (for example press on another button)
is it possible to update the values? Can I apply the doFill method in some event?

Thanks